# UTF-8 characters in pandoc template variables using knitr

Tags: r, utf-8, markdown, knitr, pandoc

Consider the simpel RMarkdown file below. I've saved it as `test.md` with UTF-8 encoding. Notice that I have embedded a custom pandoc variable 'test' in the file. This variable holds an UTF-8 character ©.

```
%My title
%The authorslist

<!--pandoc
format: latex
V: test:"Copyright notice. © copyright holder"
-->

# First section

fgsdfg jsdksdfgsdfg
```

Now I try to compile it from within R using knitr.

```
library(knitr)
pandoc("test.md", format = "latex")
```

knitr inserts an extra character in the system command to pandoc. I assume it has something to do with the encoding. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
executing pandoc -V test:"Copyright notice. Â© copyright holder"  -f markdown -t latex -o test.pdf "test.md"
```

The result of sessionInfo() on my system

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Belgium.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Belgium.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Dutch_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.1 formatR_0.10   fortunes_1.5-2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: What is your sessionInfo()? I guess your default locale is not UTF-8? In that case, I'll have to patch the pandoc() function.

Comment: I've added the info to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I guessed, your default locale is not UTF-8, in which case R cannot read an UTF8-encoded file unless you specify the encoding explicitly. I have [added](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/c6b7508) the encoding support in the `pandoc()` function, so now you can process your file using `pandoc("test.md", format = "latex", encoding = "UTF-8")`. For now, you can install the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme), which will become **knitr** v1.6 on CRAN in the future.

Comment: I have installed the development version with devtools::install_github("yihui/knitr"). It works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I hit another bug: knit("test.Rmd") gives similar problem after setting options(encoding = "UTF-8"). I renamed the example above (test.md) to test.Rmd and saved it as UTF-8 (set as default encoding in RStudio). knit("test.Rmd") with options(encoding = "native.enc") works fine.

Comment: I do not recommend `options(encoding = 'UTF-8')` under an OS that does not support UTF-8 natively. You can easily get into trouble.